# What does 倒 mean in 现在也倒没有透露我们到底为哪个峰会准备这个午宴?

Tags: meaning

Can this 倒 be omitted in this sentence? Does it work together with 也？ Is it some kind of passive marker?

(Edit: This was the previous sentence:
如果我们的主席也正好在华盛顿的话，我想他会感觉到非常自豪的，能有这么好的中午餐提供给华盛顿这些首脑。)

> 现在我们也倒没有透露我们到底为哪个峰会准备这个午宴。

Made a mistake copying; it should be:

> 现在也倒没有透露我们到底为哪个峰会准备这个午宴。

I would translate '也倒没有透露' as 'we still don't know', although it is really more like '(they) still have not revealed to us' which is passive as far as '我们' are concerned.

Comment: it implies 'at least'.

Comment: Better rephrase: 现在到底为哪个峰会准备这个午宴, 我们倒也没有透露。

Comment: ＂汉英虚词词典＂倒（副词）A 同＂反而＂，表示某一种情况产生的结果与应产生的结果相反 indicates that outcome of sth.is exactly opposite to what it should be  B 表示有点出乎意料 somewhat unexpectedly C表示比想象的要好 indicates that sth.has turned out better than one would have imagined D 肯定积极的一面，重点在下面指出消极方面 。。。while one acknowledges the favourable, one intends to point out the unfavourable E 表示与对方所想的不一样 facts are not as one may expect F 表示不耐烦，用于催促 impatience and desire to hurry so. along G ＂你倒好＂表示对对方不满意，认为他做了很不该做的事, also see bkrs and jukuu's   at least 39 samples for 倒没有

Comment: My best guess so far for this context is the speaker feel he/she felt they should/are supposed to reveal it, but on the contrary they had not. That's why 反倒没有. Otherwise, it's misuse. This is not a good example for practicing 倒没有 though, I think.

Comment: it implies that he reveals something which are not important.

Answer (score 3):

倒 is such a tricky word! I don't think(at least from I know) we have an English equivalent for it. The closest translation to English I think is "Well, (that one is different) ..."

Think about this dialogue:

> A: 可以吸烟吗？
>
> B: 不可以。
>
> A: 可以喝酒吗？
>
> B: 不可以
>
> A: 那吃东西也不行了？
>
> B: 这个倒没有限制。(Well, that might be ok.)

As you can see, 倒没有 is usually used, when a serial of questions has been asked/talked about, and at some point the questioner asks the very question which he would expect the same kind of answer but the replier knows it would be a bit surprise(to the questioner) because his answer would be reverse(倒) from those answers he had given previously.

For this case,

> 现在我们也倒没有透露我们到底为哪个峰会准备这个午宴。

There could be some other things that have been discussed in the previous context. After they have confirmed (or answered yes to) those things, and when comes to this one, they reversed the tone(倒没有) because they want to give a heads-up that this answer would be different from those previous ones.

So, I would think 倒 in this context is expressing the idea "heads-up! the tone/answer is reversed". Or compared with the previous answers, this one is reversed(倒过来了).

The more tricky part is 也 in the sentence, implying there could be another previous question which has a reversed answer already. So, this one is the second one and that's why 也 is being used.

**Updates after thinking a bit deeper(which I think this question deserves):**

This word 倒 is used when the speaker feel it's necessary to reverse the tone. This could be because of following reasons:

1. the tone is consistent for the preceding questions and at some point it changes. This is like the virtual example above.
2. the speaker feels his answer would be the exact reversed from what his listeners expect. The OP's example could fall into this reason. 现在也倒没有透露我们到底为哪个峰会准备这个午宴。It implies that the speakers feel that normally people would think they've already revealed 我们到底为哪个峰会准备这个午宴, but reversely they have not. This reason could just be the speaker's assumption(Maybe, it doesn't matter if it's true).
3. It could be a matter of idiolect. Some would use it casually without thinking that deep of the usage, especially in spoken.

Comment: In the interview, there are really no preceding questions about this.

Comment: Without detailed context, it's hard to guess. Maybe, he/she just wants to express a weak 'but'. In theory, there got to be some preceding questions/context. In practice, it depends on how people use the language. And also even native speakers could misuse the language sometimes, especially in spoken.

Comment: Thanks for that! I find 倒没有 a lot when I look. I would translate '倒没有透露'我们到底为哪个峰会准备这个午宴in my sentence 'we don't even know' for which summit meeting we should prepare a (Chinese) luncheon.

Answer (score 1):

Without 倒, it is a statement describing a basic fact.
With 倒, it implies that we should have have or hoped to have revealed ....

Answer (score 1):

There is no passive marker in the sentence. Purely from this one sentence, it means that "we" know the fact (who we are preparing lunch for) and "we" didn't reveal the fact to others.

I feel "倒" here should imply "at least", or "although":

> At least/Althogh we haven't revealed who we are preparing lunch for ....

Comment: I see 倒没有 is a fairly common collocation. I think we can translate here as 'we don't even know' (because 'they' haven't revealed （透露了）it to us）

Answer (score 1):

it means but, which expresses the fact is not what people usually think of, or is different from what people suppose to be.